# WLST - Cannot connect() with HTTPS - T3S Protocol - Port 9002

Tags: wlst

We changed the configuration of our WebLogic servers to use HTTPS and T3S for connections and use the secure encrypted port 9002 instead of cleartext port 7001. However when using the Web Logic Scripting Tool (WLST)'s connect() function, errors are thrown. One such error is as follows:

```
WLSTException: Error occurred while performing connect : Cannot connect via t3s or https. If using demo certs, verify that the -Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=DemoTrust system property is set. : t3s://DatServer:9002: Destination 10.10.100.3, 9002 unreachable; nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem; No available router to destination
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace :
```

The syntax of the connect function is: `connect('user', 'password', 't3s://host:9002')`

This connect() function works fine before the switch from HTTP to HTTPS. Now we cannot connect to the remote admin server using the connect command.  Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

I read some interesting help options but none of them seemed to work. These help suggestions and tips are located here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1036828

We were able to connect to the remote host and port via *telnet*. We saw that the port is open and listening for connections on the loop back address with *netstat*. We tried adding these options to the script invocation: `java -cp /path/to/weblogic.jar weblogic.WLST -Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=DemoTrust -Dssl.debug=true Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom` but this also did not work.

We enabled tunneling in the General tab of WebLogic but not in the HTTP tab. I am not the one in control of the server so I just have to suggest things and hope that the instructions are followed.

Answer (score 1):

I get it running in 12.2. by adding to 
../oracle_common/common/bin/setWlstEnv_internal.sh 
at the end the following lines (youu need to customize line 5 und 6, the values in brackets):

JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dweblogic.ssl.JSSEEnabled=true ${JAVA_OPTIONS}"
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dweblogic.security.SSL.enableJSSE="true" ${JAVA_OPTIONS}"
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true ${JAVA_OPTIONS}"
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=CustomTrust ${JAVA_OPTIONS}"
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dweblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreFileName= ${JAVA_OPTIONS}"
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dweblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStorePassPhrase= ${JAVA_OPTIONS}"
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dweblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreType=JKS ${JAVA_OPTIONS}"
export JAVA_OPTIONS

and modifying in
../oracle_common/common/bin/wlst_internal.sh
the line starting with 
eval '"${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java"' ${JVM_ARGS} ...
by adding ${JAVA_OPTIONS}
so that it looks as follows:
eval '"${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java"' ${JVM_ARGS} ${JAVA_OPTIONS} weblogic.WLST '"$@"'

Hope this helps, allthough modifying scripts that are named "..internal.." doesn´t give me a good feeling

Comment: Thank-you for the help. We figured out something. Instead we added the SSL options you are modifying/calling as an environment variable for the BASH shell. I found a helpful webpage on the Oracle forum. This page to be specific: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1036828 Also, I agree with you, "modifying scripts that are named '...internal...'", is scary. :)

Answer (score 1):

export this before running wlst.sh
`export WLST_PROPERTIES=" -Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=CustomTrust -Dweblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreFileName=/u01/oracle/properties/truststore.jks  -Dweblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreType=jks -Dweblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStorePassPhrase=qaz@1234  " ;`

Comment: This worked for me on 12c. And I could leave away the CustomTrustKeyStorePassPhrase